# Burger King Vs McDonalds, מן התורה או מדרבנן

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

I know this question is a little off the beaten track but still.
I saw a quote in a Sefer regarding **cooking** meat and milk together. He explains there is a difference between Mcdonald's and Burger King’s burgers. One of them is אסור from the Torah to cook and the other is a Rabbinic איסור.
Can anyone explain to me the difference between the two and how this would impact the diorssa and drabnan.
I understand one is fried and one is grilled, but I'm not sure how this would affect Halacha.

Comment: Are you able to clarify the exact difference between McDonald's and burger king in terms of how they prepare burgers? Not everyone here is familiar. The way it is cooked could 
definitely  impact the severity of the prohibition.

Comment: @robev - you hit the nail on the head. That is my exact question, I have no clue how they make it... if anyone can shed light...

Comment: I know that at one time McDonalds had the cheese slices in the buns waiting for the hot meat patty to be inserted, while at BK they actually melted the cheese onto the patty on the grill, but in the end it's the same thing because the McDonald's meat patty was at a temperature above yad soledet bo.

Comment: So far @יהושעק that makes the most sense from a practical side of things!

Comment: I feel you should ask them instead of us

Comment: With regard to cooking milk and meat together, this does not happen at either both of the francises. I know someone working at the McDonald's and asked him this question. I'll let you know what he says.... To be continued.

Comment: 2) I've spoken with my friend, who works at McDonald's. There are separate grills for baking (grilling) the burgers. The meat is grilled on the grill, transfered to the bread, cheese is put on etc....

Comment: @Shmuel meanimg the cheese slice is placed on the hot patty?

Comment: @יהושעק Nope. The meat is grilled on the grill. The cheese is already "ready to use" and is put on the burger when the bread comes out of the "oven". It is literally a slice of cheddar cheese already cut into slices.

Comment: So, let's say you order a cheeseburger, and if it is kosher, afaik, the burger didn't come into any contact with meat.

Comment: Thank you @Shmuel!!! great info
Does anyone know anyone who knows someone who knows burger king?

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy My pleasure. With regard to Burger King, I guess it is exactly the same procedure of "building a burger", although with different ingredients ofcourse.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that one is grilled and one is fried, there is room to explain as follows:

In yoreh deah siman 87 in seif 1 it states that cooking meat with milk is a biblical prohibition. The first piece of Rebbi Akiva Eiger brings  that grilling is forbidden from the torah as it is included in the prohibition of cooking meat and milk together. The pischei teshuva in seif katan 3 brings a dispute whether frying is included in the biblical prohibition, or it is a rabbinical prohibition. Accordingly, there is the potential halachic opinion that the cheeseburger that is grilled is a  biblical prohibition, and the cheeseburger that is fried is a rabbinical prohibition.

Answer (score 1):

If your presumption is correct, then *tigun*, frying, is still d'oraisa to cook (Pri Chadash). However, it might be d'rabbanan to eat. This would follow Minchat Yaakov and Aruch Hashulchan. Pri Megadim relies on Michat Yaakov in a hefsed merubeh. See SH Yora Deah 87:1-2 and commentaries

Comment: Thanks, @rabbi_kaii (Thank you for your mention earlier today)  The sefer was talking about the issue of cooking. Would love someone to answer who worked at these establishments and then became frum etc...

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy fair enough, Avrah mentioned the dispute that you are probably referring to. Good luck with this interesting question

Comment: I thought they hold Tigun is derabanan completely. How could it be doraisa Assur to cook and muttar doraisa to eat?

Comment: @robev as Avrah brought, it is a machlokes. Go check the sources b'iyun. The mitzva of bishul is separate from the mitzva of hana'ah (see sefer Hachinuch 113 for eg), so what's the hava amina?

Comment: You didn't mention hanaah, you mentioned achila, which is directly tied to the issur of bishul. If I recall correctly the Rambam and chinuch don't count a mitzvah of hanaah. I assume you just mistyped. Either way counting of mitzvos has no bearing on our discussion. דרך בישול אסרה תורה. Avrah didn't bring anyone who says like you

Comment: @robev Sefer HaChinuch explains that achila and hana'ah are grouped together (not bishul and achila?). The Rambam holds this way too (look up נקודה נפלאה). Otherwise, people hold that bishul, hana'ah and achila are 3 separate issues, and the halachos of pet foods bring this up (see Pri Megadim in the Psicha starting ula'inyan cheilev, Chatam Sofer  Yorah Deyah siman 92).

Comment: What you're saying is correct but again not relevant to halacha. Anything Assur to cook is Assur to eat. דרך בישול אסרה תורה. Nekudah niflaah is about hanaah we're discussing achila

Comment: @robev there the halacha is that achila is an extension of hana'ah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142252/discussion-between-robev-and-rabbi-kaii).

Comment: Note I see the Pri Toar 91:17 says even though meat/milk which were salted or soaked together is assur derabanan to eat, it's permitted to salt/soak them together. However, the Kaf HaCHhaim 91:73 disagrees, but he doesn't say why. I doubt he means doraisa.

Comment: I asked my Rav, he knows this stuff backwards. The closest case he could come up with to support this idea is for those who say cooking nevaila and milk is BBC d'oraisa eating it afterwards is not BBC, although it's osser to eat d'oraisa because the meat is nevaila. Furthermore, it is muter b'hanah @robev